# Searching in a rotated and sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search

I've written this code for searching using the concept of finding number of rotations in a sorted array.
I've first found the number of rotations performed on the sorted array. This gives me the index of the smallest element in the array.
Then I'm applying binary search on either of the subarrays depending on where the key would be lying.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;

ll countRotations(ll n,ll a[])
{
    ll start=0;
    ll end=n-1;
    while(start<=end)
    {
        ll mid=start+(end-start)/2;
        if(a[mid-1]<a[mid] && a[mid]<a[mid+1])
        {
            if(a[start]>a[mid])
            end=mid-1;
            else if(a[mid]>a[end])
            start=mid+1;
            else return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(a[mid]>a[mid+1])
            return mid+1;
            else
            return mid;
        }
    }
}

ll binarySearch(ll a[],ll start, ll end,ll key)
{
    while(start<=end)
    {
        ll mid=start + (end-start)/2;
        if(a[mid]==key)
        return mid;
        else if(a[mid]>key)
        end=mid-1;
        else
        start=mid+1;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() 
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        ll n;
        cin>>n;
        ll i,a[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
        ll ele;
        cin>>ele;
        ll k=countRotations(n,a);
        if(a[k]==ele)
        cout<<k;
        else if(a[n-1]>ele)
        cout<<binarySearch(a,k,n-1,ele);
        else
        cout<<binarySearch(a,0,k,ele);
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code is almost right, but it is failing in one of the test cases.

Comment: What test case is failing? What did you find out from debugging?

Comment: The entire test case is not available. I'll just give the data I was made available.
n=19265

Comment: a[] and k are in this part = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161

Comment: 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 27.................

Comment: Its Correct output is:
19264

And Your Code's output is:
-1

Comment: Idk if it helped ..